# Adding cross-region target is not permitted. If connect eventbridge between Frankfurt and ohio region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am using eventbridge aws service and  trying to set up event event rule between Ohio and frankfurt and also frankfurt & Ohio. However I am always getting an error "Adding cross-region target is not permitted."

Can anyone pls help me on same?

Comment: What rule specifically are you trying to configure, what is the target of the rule? How are you trying to set it up? Have you tried doing it via the CLI?

Comment: I need to send my ec2 instance change notification from Ohio region to frankfurt region via event bridge. So during setting up rule, I am choosing target "event bus in different account or region" with this giving my frankfurt region event bus arn. I am doing from console. Same process is working fine between Singapore and frankfurt, but not working for ohio and frankfurt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just do simple step Set up eventbridge between Ohio and Singapore. it will not work